# checking field in my sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am just a beginner in php. I am trying to write code for student registration form submission. I have the email field and name field in my form and i have to check the new entrants email address and name with the existing ones. If there is no previous existence my form should submit otherwise it should ask for the another email address and name. I used the following code.

```
<?php

$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `intStudentId`  FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE `varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
$res = mysql_query($sel);
if(mysql_num_rows($res) >0)
{ ?>
<h3 style="color:#FF0000;">The Email Address already exists. Please mention different Email Address.</h3>
<?php
}

else
     {

 $insertstudent="INSERT INTO `tbl_registration` (
`varFname` ,
`varLname` ,
`varAddress` ,
`varGender` ,
`intDOB` ,
`varEmail`
)
VALUES (
'".$fname."',  '".$lname."',  '".$address."',  '".$gender."',  '".$DOB."',  '".$emailaddress."'
);";
$insert_res = mysql_query($insertstudent);
     }




?>
```

I have to check the email duplication and name duplication only. How to modify my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need  AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' in there?

Comment: @designersvsoft,You say:"... check the new entrants email address with the existing ones."  So, removing intStudentid from query  is not a good decision.

Comment: Sorry. Now i edited my question. Please guide me

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if email is used before

```
 WHERE varEmail = '$emailaddress'
```

will be enough. If you want to check a certain student with certain email

```
 WHERE varEmail = '$emailaddress' AND name='$studentName'
```

If you want to check student name only

```
 WHERE  name='$studentName'
```

will do it, but this is problematic  because many students may have same name.