# checking duplication of form values in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write code for registration form which have the following fields. Name, Email address, Date of birth, Address etc. If The new entrants name and email address match with the
existing one it should ask for another name and email.

I used the following code.

```
<?php
$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `intStudentId`  FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE `varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
$res = mysql_query($sel);
if(mysql_num_rows($res) >0)
{ ?>
<h3 style="color:#FF0000; text-align:center;">The Email Address and name already exists. Please mention different one.</h3>
<?php
}

else
     {

 $insertstudent="INSERT INTO `tbl_registration` (
`varFname` ,
`varLname` ,
`varAddress` ,
`varGender` ,
`intDOB` ,
`varEmail`
)
VALUES (
'".$fname."',  '".$lname."',  '".$address."',  '".$gender."',  '".$DOB."',  '".$emailaddress."'
);";
$insert_res = mysql_query($insertstudent);
     }

?>
```

But it only checks the email duplication. How can i modify my code to check both name and email duplication?

Comment: double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849224/checking-field-in-my-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wich namefield should be checked? fname, lname or both?

for firstname:

```
$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `intStudentId`  FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE (`varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' OR `varFname` = '".$fname."') AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
```

for lastname:

```
$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `intStudentId`  FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE (`varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' OR `varLname` = '".$lname."') AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
```

for both:

```
$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `intStudentId`  FROM `tbl_registration` WHERE (`varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' OR (`varLname` = '".$lname."' AND `varFname` = '".$fname."')) AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
```

Comment: I think this is a comment, not an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

First line:

```
$sel = "SELECT `varEmail`, `varLname`, `intStudentId` 
        FROM `tbl_registration` 
        WHERE `varEmail` = '".$emailaddress."' 
            AND `varLname` = '".$name."' 
            AND `intStudentId` <> '".$Id."' ";
```

where **varLname** is you db field name for name and **$name** is value you take from form.

Comment: this will only work if email AND name is the same, i think it should check email or name

Comment: From the first post: "If The new entrants name **and** email address match with the existing one it should ask for another name and email."

:-)

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of your select I can see that you check for the email but not the name, you need to add that to your query...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it without **additional** SELECT query.

These fields can be unique; just add complex unique key (name, email).

Now, we have two variants:

1. Use INSERT statement to add new records and you will get an error on duplication, catch this error and ask user for another name and email.
2. Use INSERT statement with IGNORE option, it will help you to avoid errors, then call [mysql_affected_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) function to find out how many rows were affected; if 0, then ask user for another name and email.